# Script to push and pull all images from nexus to harbor

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-image, harbor

i want to pull from nexus all images and push them in harbor i try to do that

- `docker login -u -p https://harbor.domaine.com/`
- `docker tag nexus.domaine.com/tag:number harbor.domaine.com/project_name/tag:number`

but the problem is that i have a lot of images and if i do this operation i need to write 1 line for every images so i want something like a loop too pull and push all images from nexus any help ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use bash script, for example

```
#!/bin/bash
docker login -u -p https://harbor.domaine.com/
for image_name in $(docker images --format="{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" | grep nexus.domaine.com)
do
  new_image_name=$(echo $image_name | sed 's/nexus.domaine.com/harbor.domaine.com\/project_name/')
  docker tag $image_name $new_image_name
  docker push $new_image_name
done
```

Comment: that's work for me thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing [regsync](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) to do exactly this. For a quick start, there's a [workshop](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/presentations/tree/main/reg-mirror-2021/workshop) I recently gave at the docker all-hands, which includes not only the copy, but also the cleanup steps, or there's the [quick start](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/blob/main/docs/regsync-quickstart.md) in the project itself.

To implement, create a regsync.yml:

```yaml
version: 1
creds:
  - registry: nexus.domaine.com
    # credentials here
  - registry: harbor.domaine.com
    # credentials here
defaults:
  parallel: 2
  interval: 60m
sync:
  - source: nexus.domaine.com/image
    target: harbor.domaine.com/project_name/image
    type: repository
```

And then run regsync:

```
docker container run -it --rm \
  -v "$(pwd)/regsync.yml:/home/appuser/regsync.yml:ro" \
  regclient/regsync:latest -c /home/appuser/regsync.yml once
```

Comment: i will try this solution too, Thank you!